# vim 'source' vs. 'exe/execute' commands

Tags: vim

What is the difference between doing (in my `.vimrc`):

```
set runtimepath+=$HOME/.vim/conf
source ~/.vim/conf/hotkeys.vim
```

and

```
set runtimepath+=$HOME/.vim/conf
exe 'source' '~/.vim/conf/hotkeys.vim'
```

Do the contents of my script (in this case `hotkeys.vim`) have anything to do with which I should use?

Also, is there any difference at all between the `exe`, `exec` and `execute` commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, there would be no difference between using `source` and `execute`.

The `source` method is simply loading a static file path.

The `execute` version evaluates the strings it is given, but ultimately all it does is run the exact same `source` command as the first example.

The difference would come in if you didn't know the filename ahead of time, and had to calculate it, or obtain it from some other source. Then you could construct a source command like this:

```
" A file name we obtained from user input or some other source
let g:file_we_want = 'foo'

" Calculate a file path as a string
let g:path_to_source = '~/' . g:file_we_want . '.vim'

" This is equivalent to:
"     source ~/foo.vim
execute 'source' g:path_to_source
```

There is no difference between `exe`, `exec`, and `execute`. They are all the same command. `exe` and `exec` are abbreviations.

Comment: Oh okay I got it. Thanks a lot!